# The timer counting error of linux device driver based on S3C2440

Tags: c, linux, timer, hardware

I write a linux device driver to learn the infrared coding of remote control.

XINT0(GPIOF0) is used to reiceive the signal from infrared diode. Timer0 is used to count in the XINT0 interrupt hander programme to record the period of High Voltage level and Low Voltage level.

The configurations of GPIO and Timer are suitable. The initial value of Timer0 in TCNTB is 50000, sometimes the periods of voltage level are correct， but sometimes the obervation value of TCNT0 is 50000, which shows that the timer does not work normally.

in every interrupt loop, the observation value is print as follows.

```
<4>current observation value: 49786
<4>current observation value: 49702
<4>current observation value: 50000
<4>current observation value: 49969
<4>current observation value: 50000
<4>current observation value: 49996
<4>current observation value: 50000
<4>current observation value: 49998
<4>current observation value: 47827
<4>current observation value: 49392
<4>current observation value: 49906
<4>current observation value: 50000
<4>current observation value: 49970
<4>current observation value: 50000
<4>current observation value: 49997
<4>current observation value: 50000
<4>current observation value: 49998
<4>current observation value: 50000
```

Here's the code:

```
static irqreturn_t gpio_study_irq_handler(int irq, void *wbuf)
{
  unsigned int *buf=(unsigned int *)wbuf;
  unsigned int temp;
  if(0==IrDA_cnt){
    timer_setup(&Study_Timer,MAX_CODE_WIDTH);
    timer_on(&Study_Timer);
    IrDA_cnt++;
    return IRQ_RETVAL(IRQ_HANDLED);
  }
  temp=ioread32(Study_Timer.tcnto);
  timer_off(&Study_Timer);      
  printk("current observation value: %d\n",temp);
  *(buf+IrDA_cnt-1)=MAX_CODE_WIDTH-read_timer_cnt(&Study_Timer);
  iowrite32(MAX_CODE_WIDTH,Study_Timer.tcntb);

  temp=ioread32(Study_Timer.tcon);
  iowrite32(temp|0x02,Study_Timer.tcon);
  temp=ioread32(Study_Timer.tcon);
  iowrite32(temp&(~0x02),Study_Timer.tcon);

  timer_on(&Study_Timer);
  IrDA_cnt++;
  if(IrDA_cnt > CODE_MAX_LEN)
  {
    wake_up_interruptible(&IrDA_Study_Queue);
    return IRQ_RETVAL(IRQ_HANDLED);
  }
  return IRQ_RETVAL(IRQ_HANDLED);
}
```

Comment: TCNT0 updation from GPIO need some delay when CPU resource is Busy. Apply sleep for small delay after ioread32.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have found the solution. The **printk** takes up too much time. When at last the timer is turn on, the interrupt request has come, leading to the constant value of observation value.

Comment: You can answer your own question then ;)

Comment: Are you using a bare IR diode, not [a dedicated IR receiver with carrier filtering](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10266)? That's ... hardcore to do in software that high-level.

Comment: I am using the dedicated IR receiver with carrier filtering as in the link. The problem arises in software. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The system function **printk** takes up too much time in the IRQ service handler. When at last the timer is turn on, the interrupt request has come, leading to the constant value of observation value.